# What function does C-x invoke?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, commands

I learned that `M-x` invokes command `execute-extended-command`.

[Extended commands - GNU Emacs FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Extended-commands.html)

What command does `C-x` invoke?
I looked through the reference but failed to find the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the default configuration, it is not a complete key sequence: it is a [prefix](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html#Prefix-Keys) key. It is an incomplete specification: it has to be followed by another key (or more than one, if the next key is also a prefix key) before it gets you to a complete key sequence (i.e. one that is bound to a command).

E.g. `C-x C-f` is bound to the command `find-file` (by default), `C-x f` is bound to `set-fill-column` and `C-x n` is bound to another prefix key, which could be completed with e.g. another `n`: `C-x n n` is bound to the command `narrow-to-region`. See the section on [keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Keymaps.html#Keymaps) in the Emacs Lisp manual for details.

Comment: To see which key sequences _start_ with `C-x`, type `C-x C-h` (this works for any prefix key in place of `C-x`).